# How to strip unwanted html tags from a text file?

Tags: python, text-files

I have a txt file that contains some random emails. My script is pulling emails into this text file several times per day and each email has `<start>` and `<end>` to distinguish where it begins and ends. I would like to clean up my file and remove unwanted parts which are mostly html tags and keep only the email body part string as a separate row in txt file for each email. What would be the best way to strip html tags from my file in order to keep only the string that is included within body tags?

There is also one type of email that has Id attribute and not sure how I could get this to be present with the email body string (see first line in output.txt).

myTxt.txt:

```
<start><html> <head>    <title>A random title</title>   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> </head> <body> Hello World, Have a great day  Thanks <br><br> <hr> <br> <b>Details:</b><br><br> Name: John Doe<br><br> Email: johndoe@gmail.com<br><br> Secondary Name: Joe<br><br> Reference URL: <a href="https://some-url.com/Id=03415681&returnUrl=%2Fui%2F2%2Femail%2Faccount%3Ffind%3D" style="text-decoration: none; color: #08c;">/ui/2/email/account?Id=03415681&returnUrl=%2Fui%2F2%2Femail%2Faccount%3Ffind%3D</a><br> </body> <img src='https://path/to/img.gif?v=RL9lKY7Jm6AY0Gc3tHa9'/> </html> <end>
<start><div>Hello World, How are you?    Best.</div> <end>
<start>Hello World.<end>
<start>Hello World, this is my message.


Regards,

Jane

www.url.com

<end>
<start><html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office1" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word1" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/121/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html401"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face   {font-family:"Cambria Math";    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;} @font-face   {font-family:DengXian;  panose-1:2 1 6 0 3 1 1 1 1 1;} @font-face   {font-family:Calibri;   panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} @font-face  {font-family:"\@DengXian";  panose-1:2 1 6 0 3 1 1 1 1 1;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal     {margin:0cm;    margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:11.0pt;   font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink    {mso-style-priority:99;     color:blue;     text-decoration:underline;} .MsoChpDefault  {mso-style-type:export-only;} @page WordSection1    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;  margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;} div.WordSection1   {page:WordSection1;} --></style></head><body lang=EN-MY link=blue vlink="#954F72"><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hello World, </p><p class=MsoNormal></p><p class=MsoNormal>This is my message. </p><p class=MsoNormal></p><p class=MsoNormal>Please reply when you can. </p><p class=MsoNormal></p><p class=MsoNormal>Thank you.<br>John</p><p class=MsoNormal>Sent from <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=1234567890">Mail</a> for Windows 10</p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>Â </o:p></p></div></body></html> <end>
```

desired output.txt:

```
Hello World, Have a great day Thanks Id=0341568115681
Hello World, How are you? Best.
Hello World.
Hello World, this is my message. Regards, Jane www.url.com
Hello World, Please reply when you can. Thank you.John Sent from Mailfor Windows 10Â
```

my code so far:

```
#adding <start> <end> tags to make clear separation between different emails and saving it to a file. 
#'emails' variable below contains all the emails that were captured when script ran

file = 'path/to/myTxt.txt'
start= '<start>'
end = '<end>'
toTXT = [start + s + end for s in emails]
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(map(str, toTXT)))
```

Could someone help with this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: sorry about this. Thought that question in title would suffice, edited.

Comment: Don't add `<start>` and `<end>` tags, use normal `<start>...</start>`. Then you can use for example `beautifulsoup` module to filter out the tags and get only the text.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
>>> a = '''<start><html> <head>    <title>A random title</title>   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> </head> <body> Hello World, Have a great day  Thanks <br><br> <hr> <br> <b>Details:</b><br><br> Name: John Doe<br><br> Email: johndoe@gmail.com<br><br> Secondary Name: Joe<br><br> Reference URL: <a href="https://some-url.com/Id=03415681&returnUrl=%2Fui%2F2%2Femail%2Faccount%3Ffind%3D" style="text-decoration: none; color: #08c;">/ui/2/email/account?Id=03415681&returnUrl=%2Fui%2F2%2Femail%2Faccount%3Ffind%3D</a><br> </body> <img src='https://path/to/img.gif?v=RL9lKY7Jm6AY0Gc3tHa9'/> </html> <end>
... <start><div>Hello World, How are you?    Best.</div> <end>
... <start>Hello World.<end>
... <start>Hello World, this is my message.
... '''
>>> import re
>>> print ' '.join([i.strip(' ') for i in re.split( r'<[^>]+>', a ) if len(i.strip(' ')) > 0])
A random title Hello World, Have a great day  Thanks Details: Name: John Doe Email: johndoe@gmail.com Secondary Name: Joe Reference URL: /ui/2/email/account?Id=03415681&returnUrl=%2Fui%2F2%2Femail%2Faccount%3Ffind%3D 
 Hello World, How are you?    Best. 
 Hello World. 
 Hello World, this is my message.

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
import re
def striphtml(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)
print(striphtml("<h2>Some text</h2>"))
```

Output:`Some text`